# Ngif Not Functional in html

Tags: angular, typescript

```
HTML
<div *ngIf="isFilterPanelOpen == !isFilterPanelOpen">

TS
export class Component implements OnInit {
  isFilterPanelOpen: boolean = false; 
}
```

In my TS file, I am using `isFilterPanelOpen`as a boolean. and then checking the condition in the HTML. I actually want to show the filters on button click and hiding them on again click Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: What happened to SO?

Answer (score 2):

```
in ts file--->  
isFilterPanelOpen : boolean = false;

visibleMethod(){
  if(<<<<my condition>>>) this.isFilterPanelOpen=true;
  else this.isFilterPanelOpen=false;
  }
int htmll file ---
<div *ngIf="isFilterPanelOpen>Test</div>
 <button (click)="visibleMethod()">Please click to hide</button>
```

You can maket like that

Answer (score 0):

*ngIf="isFilterPanelOpen == !isFilterPanelOpen is never True
a variable can't not be the negate of her self

try this *ngIf="isFilterPanelOpen"

Comment: already tried this this is also not functional :

Comment: yes, because the condition is false, if you set isFilterPanelOpen: boolean = false; to true you will see the div and its content

Comment: i actually want to show the filters on click and hide the filters if the button is clicked again

Comment: So you have to use (click) = "isFilterPanelOpen =! IsFilterPanelOpen" in an html element as a button to show and hide dynamically

Answer (score 0):

```
<div *ngIf="isFilterPanelOpen == !isFilterPanelOpen"> it will never return true.
```

Use in following way

```
<div *ngIf="isFilterPanelOpen></div>
```

Comment: the thing is want to show the filters on one click and on clicking again the filters will hide

Answer (score 0):

Bind the boolean flag toggle to button click handler.

```html
<button (click)="isFilterPanelOpen = !isFilterPanelOpen">Toggle filter</button>

<div *ngIf="isFilterPanelOpen">Filter open</div>
```